# Should I delete my similar answer or flag it for moderator?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522051/why-is-equals-method-not-called-in-the-hashmap/24522277#24522277), I try to answer the question. But when I finish my answer and long time human verification (for my net speed is very slow), I saw someone has very similar answer with me. So, what should I do? Deleting my similar answer or flaging it for moderator or any other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it if you wish, or delete it. Do not flag it; there’s nothing for a moderator to do. If you think any of the other answers are helpful, you should upvote them.